# EXCEL like table in eclipse GEF

Tags: excel, eclipse

I have a project that need to create several graphic editing.

A new feature is to create a excel like table using GEF.

Column / Row add/delete is needed.

The current plan is to many Node. As add new column / row, add lots of Node to make it like a table.
About the Node width / height adjustment, the current plan is use can adjust size of each Node.
Other corresponding node will be change according the current node change.

Currently some tests is working, but I wonder if there are better solution this this?

(Using plan SWT table is not ok, for some GEF feature is still needed.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to render the excel table on Canvas than using GEF figures to represent column/row..etc. Because you will not be able to optimize performance with GEF as its `UpdateManager`(that does painting) is very generic and it doesn't know about a thing about excel like behavior that you are looking for.